# Effect for image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, effects, onmouseover

look this:

[image]

When the pointer is on the image I want a small dark rect at the bottom of this image with some text. How can I do this? Maybe with jquery?

Thanks guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90579/how-to-center-text-over-an-image-in-a-table-using-javascript-css-and-or-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can easily use jquery to achieve that.
If you want to learn the whole process and do it yourself, take a look at this - [Sliding Boxes and Captions with jQuery](http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/)
Or take a look at a few plugins for achieving the same effect - [10 Stylish jQuery caption plugins](http://www.net-kit.com/10-jquery-caption-plugins/)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this many ways. Depending on the structure of your page, you could accomplish this with a couple of CSS classes.

HTML:

```
<div class="image_hover"><span>Text</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image_hover { background-image: url("path/to/image"); height: 95px; width: 270px; }
.image_hover span { display: none; }
.image_hover:hover span { display: block; position: relative; top: 80px; width: 270px; text-align: center; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; }
```

You would need to make some updates based on your particular situation. Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/ojofi4/edit) on jsbin. This solution hides the text by default, and when the user hovers over the div, the :hover class will cause the text to be displayed.

You could also use jQuery to either add or show the div onmouseover.